# Android: System bar won't hide. LogCat (No such file or directory; request rejected (service call activity 79 s16 com.android.systemui)

Tags: android, statusbar, logcat

I've got an self written app that shoult hide or restore the systembar. This app is running on an Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (P7500). I've got two Tabs. One rooted with stock Galaxy ROM and one rooted with Overcome ROM.

I looked at this tutorial to hide the bar ( http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=306 )

My methods look like this:

```
private void hideStatusBar() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity 79 s16 com.android.systemui"});
proc.waitFor();
}

private void showStatusBar() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"am","startservice","-n","com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService"});
proc.waitFor();
}
```

If I click on my buttons an the methods are called I can see that something is happening because the app is waiting some seconds. I also looked into LogCat and see that something is happening.

show: http://pastebin.com/CidTRSTi hide:

http://pastebin.com/iPS6Kgbp

I guess the problem with hide is in line 57

So I tried an app in the market: TabBar Hider Demo ( https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tlalexander.tabletbarhiderdemo&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLnRsYWxleGFuZGVyLnRhYmxldGJhcmhpZGVyZGVtbyJd )

But here the same. The bar won't remove/hide. I also looked into LogCat

show: http://pastebin.com/TuKXQ5qm

hide: http://pastebin.com/rWHFQV4u

Same problem in line 51 (hide)

Any hints?
Thx B770

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the non rooted tablet, this is to be expected.

on the rooted tablet, it soulds like it can't find the su binary.  open a shell (eg, from your pc/mac, type 'adb shell' or use a terminal app from the market), and see what happens if you type su.  on a non rooted device you should get an error saying su not found whereas on the rooted device you shouldn't.  if you do get this error, then your rooted rom is not including su.  goto xda forums and find either a different rom or how to add su

Comment: Thx, that was the prob. I granted su rights and everything works just fine. :)